# Block diagonalizing a spin-chain Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, ising-model, spin-chains

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$

I am learning about exact diagonalization methods, currently following [this explanation](http://physics.bu.edu/~sandvik/vietri/dia.pdf). My question is in regards to the part where we utilize the fact that the Hamiltonian conserves the total spin to block-diagonalize it. In this explanation it says that "block-diagonalization just amounts to including states with only given $m_z$," and the process is to simply compute individual blocks with different total magnetization.

My question is, how is this different than simply rearranging the order of the states? If I initially construct the Hamiltonian in the "binary basis", where $\ket{0} \equiv \ket{\cdots 0000} \equiv \ket{\cdots \downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow}, \ldots, \ket{5} \equiv \ket{\cdots 0101} \equiv \ket{\cdots \downarrow \uparrow \downarrow\uparrow}$, etc, then I want to reorder the basis such that the states are grouped by their total spin $m_z$, and I do this by permuting the rows and columns of the Hamiltonian which I obtained in the binary basis.

For example, for $N=4$, the states $\ket{3}\equiv \ket{0011}$ and $\ket{5}\equiv \ket{0101}$ both have $m_z = 2$, while $\ket{4} \equiv \ket{0100}$ has $m_z = 1$. So I swap rows 3 and 4 and then columns 3 and 4, which I thought would just correspond to reordering the basis states as $\left\{\ket{0},\ket{1} ,\ket{2}, \ket{4},\ket{3},\ket{5},\ldots\right\}$. It seems to me that if I reorder the states such that all those with the same $m_z$ are adjacent then the resulting matrix should be block diagonal.

I have written a code to swap rows and columns of the Hamiltonian such that they are ordered from maximum $m_z$ to minimum $m_z$, but the resulting matrix is not block diagonal. So do I have a bug in my code or is my logic incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

[Note: I'm not happy with the values you assign to overall magnetization, for me, it's more natural to think of, say, $|\downarrow \uparrow \downarrow\uparrow\rangle$ as having $m_z=0$ (ups and downs cancel each other), and I'll use this terminology in my answer.]

This might only be a partial answer to your question, but it should help you moving forward. The central problem, I believe, is that you're swapping the wrong rows/columns.

Consider the case $N=3$ of the spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ $XXX$ model, which is the first non-trivial example (in the sense of not already being ordered by total magnetization). In the bit notation you introduced, you'll find that $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$ and $|4\rangle$ have $m_z=-1$, while $|3\rangle$, $|5\rangle$ and $|6\rangle$ have $m_z=1$. To obtain a block-diagonal Hamiltonian in spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ representation (i.e. local spin operators are represented by the familiar Pauli matrices), you would want to swap those parts in the Hamiltonian $H$ that affect the states $|3\rangle$ and $|4\rangle$.

By representing a spin up through $|\uparrow\rangle=(1,0)^T$ and using the Kronecker product to express $|3\rangle=|\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow\rangle=|\uparrow\rangle \otimes |\uparrow\rangle\otimes | \downarrow\rangle$ etc, you'll find that $|3\rangle$ is an eight-dimensional vector which has a "1" in position 2, while $|4\rangle$ is a vector with zeroes everywhere apart from position 7. Clearly, the 2nd (resp. 7th) column of the matrix $H$. Ideally, write down the 3-site matrix explicitly to check if that does the job.

I also recommend [this introduction](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nepomechie/primer.pdf) to spin chains which might clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rearranging the states according to $m_z$ DOES make the Hamiltonian block-diagonal. How did you check that the resultant is block-diagonal? Maybe you generated the block-diagonal Hamiltonian the way Sandvik suggests and then compared it your rearrangement. The problem here is that Sandvik arranges states in ascending order even within each block. I added an additional term $\dfrac{i}{2^{N+1}}$ to the $m_z$ value of each state represented by integer $i$ and then sorted them which introduces correct order within blocks and compared that to Sandvik's approach by explicitly constructing each block and then making a block-diagonal matrix using $\mathtt{scipy.linalg.block\_diag}$.